# Equivalent of time.sleep from python in ruby

Tags: python, ruby, time, sleep

I am trying to write  program in ruby which needs to make a pause before returning text.
In python you can do this by importing time and then using time.sleep(x).  How would one go about doing this in ruby.

Ex. in Python
    `print ("you say hello")

    time.sleep(5)

    print ("I say goodbye")`

Comment: I searched for something similar to the title of my question "time.sleep ruby".  Since I did not think to search for "Ruby wait" I did not see the original question.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: when I search "time.sleep ruby" or "sleep ruby" or "wait ruby" the question that I linked to is always the first or second page...

Comment: when I search "time.sleep ruby" I get 9 results (including mine).  None of which show the original answer you posted.  However "sleep ruby" shows the original question at the top of the page.  Like I said I searched time.sleep ruby so I would not have seen the link you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example, just use

```
sleep(5)
```